# Error code 1582: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'FROM_UNIXTIME'

Tags: php, mysql

My code is like:

```
$current = time();
$nexttime = mktime($hour,$minute,$second,$month,$day,$year); //$hour...from a table
```

and mySQL statement is like:

```
INSERT INTO table(...) values 
('FROM_UNIXTIME(".$current.")', 'FROM_UNIXTIME(".$nexttime.")');
```

I found the first `FROM_UNIXTIME(".$current.")` is accepted by mySQL, while the second `FROM_UNIXTIME(".$nexttime.")` shows

> Error code 1582: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'FROM_UNIXTIME'.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Why not insert the datetime literal `"$year-$month-$day $hour:$minute:$second"`?

Comment: i tried that before i use FROM_UNIXTIME(), but it failed, the result is 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in mySQL.

Comment: post the complete construction of the query, as it seems there's something weird with the quotes (your first `FROM_UNIXTIME` is wrapped in single quotes, while the latter is not wrapped)

Comment: what is your column datatype?

Comment: column datatype is datatime

Comment: sorry, i fix the second FROM_UNIXTIME.

Comment: try doing `echo $query` to print the actual query string to screen. This will probably show you what the problem is with the query.

Answer (score 3):

Remove the quotes, MySQL functions must be outside the quotes (or else it's handled as a string).

```
INSERT INTO table(...) values 
    (FROM_UNIXTIME(".$current."), FROM_UNIXTIME(".$nexttime."));
```